# How to compile a complete list of valid TLD and ccTLD domain extensions

Tags: domains

Most domain extension lists i've found only list the ccTLD and TLD portion of the extension (e.g. `.uk`) and don't list the full set of valid extensions for that ccTLD or TLD (e.g. `.org.uk`, `.ac.uk`, `.co.uk`, etc).

Without researching the registrar policies of every single ccTLD in the world, is there a way for me to compile/obtain a complete list of all current valid domain extensions in the world?

Answer (score 3):

I found what I was looking for at *The Public Suffix List*.

http://publicsuffix.org

Comment: +1 - I was going to link to this, if only I'd seen your question earlier

Answer (score 0):

[List of TLDs](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) ([human-friendly version](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/))

Comment: Thanks, but you missed the crucial part of my question. I don't need just the `.uk` or `.au` bits, I need the `.com.au`, `.co.uk`, `.org.nz` and so forth, than many ccTLDs use.